# React won't render component in a Route until refresh (not react-redux connected component)

Tags: reactjs, routes, page-refresh, react-component

I am trying to route to a new component page but react won't render it until I refresh the page.
I have found many similar posts already, but most of them are addressing react-redux connected components -- mine is not react-redux connected and I wonder if there's a fix for that.

```
<Route
  path="/somepath"
  render={(props) => (<ViewProject someprop={somethingImported} />)}
/>
```

Btw, I thought using the render prompt would work but it doesn't.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show us full router setup code.

Comment: show us more code